# Warning message, "clip" is not a graphical parameter

Tags: r, clip, terra

I get these warning messages when I try to plot this raster in terra. I suspect it's something to do with my plot parameter settings, but changing plot margins and xpd doesn't help.
Any ideas please?

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
plot(r)

#Warning messages:
#1: In plot.window(...) : "clip" is not a graphical parameter
#2: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : "clip" is not a graphical parameter
#3: In title(...) : "clip" is not a graphical parameter
#Warning messages:
#1: In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
#  "clip" is not a graphical parameter
```

```
par()
$xlog
[1] FALSE

$ylog
[1] FALSE

$adj
[1] 0.5

$ann
[1] TRUE

$ask
[1] FALSE

$bg
[1] "white"

$bty
[1] "o"

$cex
[1] 1

$cex.axis
[1] 1

$cex.lab
[1] 1

$cex.main
[1] 1.2

$cex.sub
[1] 1

$cin
[1] 0.15 0.20

$col
[1] "black"

$col.axis
[1] "black"

$col.lab
[1] "black"

$col.main
[1] "black"

$col.sub
[1] "black"

$cra
[1] 18 24

$crt
[1] 0

$csi
[1] 0.2

$cxy
[1] 0.03072334 0.02643172

$din
[1] 10.375  6.475

$err
[1] 0

$family
[1] ""

$fg
[1] "black"

$fig
[1] 0 1 0 1

$fin
[1] 10.375  6.475

$font
[1] 1

$font.axis
[1] 1

$font.lab
[1] 1

$font.main
[1] 2

$font.sub
[1] 1

$lab
[1] 5 5 7

$las
[1] 0

$lend
[1] "round"

$lheight
[1] 1

$ljoin
[1] "round"

$lmitre
[1] 10

$lty
[1] "solid"

$lwd
[1] 1

$mai
[1] 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.8

$mar
[1] 2 2 2 4

$mex
[1] 1

$mfcol
[1] 1 1

$mfg
[1] 1 1 1 1

$mfrow
[1] 1 1

$mgp
[1] 3 1 0

$mkh
[1] 0.001

$new
[1] FALSE

$oma
[1] 0 0 0 0

$omd
[1] 0 1 0 1

$omi
[1] 0 0 0 0

$page
[1] TRUE

$pch
[1] 1

$pin
[1] 9.175 5.675

$plt
[1] 0.03855422 0.92289157 0.06177606 0.93822394

$ps
[1] 12

$pty
[1] "m"

$smo
[1] 1

$srt
[1] 0

$tck
[1] NA

$tcl
[1] -0.5

$usr
[1]  5.197878  7.077122 49.441667 50.191667

$xaxp
[1] 5.5 7.0 3.0

$xaxs
[1] "r"

$xaxt
[1] "s"

$xpd
[1] NA

$yaxp
[1] 49.5 50.1  6.0

$yaxs
[1] "r"

$yaxt
[1] "s"

$ylbias
[1] 0.2
```

```
sessionInfo()

R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=English_Australia.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] tidyterra_0.4.0     terra_1.7-18        amt_0.2.1.0         lubridate_1.9.2     forcats_1.0.0       stringr_1.5.0      
 [7] dplyr_1.1.0         purrr_1.0.1         readr_2.1.4         tidyr_1.3.0         tibble_3.2.0        tidyverse_2.0.0    
[13] move_4.1.12         rgdal_1.6-5         raster_3.6-20       sp_1.6-0            geosphere_1.5-18    moveVis_0.10.5     
[19] leafem_0.2.0        leaflet_2.1.2       mapview_2.11.0      rnaturalearth_0.3.2 ggspatial_1.1.8     gganimate_1.0.8    
[25] gifski_1.6.6-1      sf_1.0-12           ggmap_3.0.2         ggplot2_3.4.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-7        satellite_1.0.4     webshot_0.5.4       progress_1.2.2      httr_1.4.5          rprojroot_2.0.3    
 [7] tools_4.2.3         utf8_1.2.3          R6_2.5.1            KernSmooth_2.23-20  DBI_1.1.3           colorspace_2.1-0   
[13] withr_2.5.0         tidyselect_1.2.0    prettyunits_1.1.1   curl_5.0.0          compiler_4.2.3      cli_3.6.0          
[19] av_0.8.3            xml2_1.3.3          scales_1.2.1        classInt_0.4-9      pbapply_1.7-0       proxy_0.4-27       
[25] digest_0.6.31       base64enc_0.1-3     jpeg_0.1-10         pkgconfig_2.0.3     htmltools_0.5.4     fastmap_1.1.1      
[31] htmlwidgets_1.6.2   rlang_1.1.0         rstudioapi_0.14     farver_2.1.1        generics_0.1.3      jsonlite_1.8.4     
[37] crosstalk_1.2.0     magrittr_2.0.3      Matrix_1.5-3        Rcpp_1.0.10         munsell_0.5.0       fansi_1.0.4        
[43] lifecycle_1.0.3     stringi_1.7.12      plyr_1.8.8          grid_4.2.3          parallel_4.2.3      crayon_1.5.2       
[49] lattice_0.20-45     cowplot_1.1.1       splines_4.2.3       hms_1.1.3           magick_2.7.4        pillar_1.9.0       
[55] codetools_0.2-19    stats4_4.2.3        glue_1.6.2          tzdb_0.3.0          png_0.1-8           vctrs_0.6.0        
[61] tweenr_2.0.2        Rdpack_2.4          RgoogleMaps_1.4.5.3 gtable_0.3.3        slippymath_0.3.1    cachem_1.0.7       
[67] rbibutils_2.2.13    lwgeom_0.2-11       e1071_1.7-13        class_7.3-21        survival_3.5-3      memoise_2.0.1      
[73] units_0.8-1         timechange_0.2.0    here_1.0.1
```

Comment: This is not related to your par settings. If something does not seem to work well, first update the R packages. You can do update.packages(ask=FALSE). Also, try things in an entirely empty workspace (and then only load terra, no other packages).

Comment: Thank you, you were right, it certainly wasn't a problem with par settings. After lots and LOTS of messing around I finally fixed it by rightclicking the RStudio icon on my desktop and selecting 'Troubleshoot compatibility'. I guess it was a problem with RStudio installation, which was then fixed :)